# S3 Boto Install Generates ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six' in Django 3

Tags: python, django, boto3

I have been reading that Django3 has removed access to libraries that use "Six".

I use S3 Boto which I installed with:

```
pip3 install boto3
```

I now get the error:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3BotoStorage
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.six import BytesIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six'
```

Is there an Django 3 compatible version of boto3 and how can I install it?